# looking for an awk gsub|sub|gensub equivalent to sed substitution

Tags: awk, sed

I am using the following sed command which I would like to transfer to awk to change the date from *2023-12-15* to *15/12/2023*:

```
echo "c_az_6332,2023-12-15,-24.01,BP_Connect,Particulars,details" \
 | sed 's/\(....\)-\(..\)-\(..\)/\3\/\2\/\1/g'
```

which results in

```
c_az_6332,15/12/2023,-24.01,BP_Connect,Particulars,details
```

How can I do the same using awk gsub|sub|gensub?

I have tried the following:

```
echo "c_az_6332,2023-12-15,-24.01,BP_Connect,Particulars,details" \
 | awk -F "," '{gsub(\(....\)-\(..\)-\(..\),\3\/\2\/\1,$2) ; print $0}'
```

and

```
echo "c_az_6332,2023-12-15,-24.01,BP_Connect,Particulars,details" \
 | awk -F "," '{gsub(/\(....\)-\(..\)-\(..\)/,\3\/\2\/\1,$2) ; print $0}'
```

both won't work. Can someone please help with this?

Comment: Keep your date in the industry standard format and use your reporting tool to give whiny users their `15/12/2023` formatted date.  As you've discovered, `gsub` doesn't support `\3\2\1` grouping. If your boss is making you do this, then you'll have to parse out those values yourself and rearrange them. `n=split($2,"-",dtArr); print {dtArr[3]"/"dtArr[2]"/"dtArr[1]` will give you a start. Good luck.

Comment: (I edited your question so readers could see the relevant code without having to scroll to see what you were doing.)

Comment: Your sed command will matching a date anywhere across the whole line rather than in one field and if it finds multiple dates on a line it'll change all of them instead of just 1 (courtesy of the `g` at the end). Do you REALLY want an awk script that does both of those things or do you want an awk script that only changes the date in the 2nd `,`-separated field as your awk scripts are attempting to do?

Comment: Would you REALLY want `2023-05-07` to become `07/05/2023` or should it become `7/5/2023`?

Comment: I just want the date to be changed in the second column not across potential dates in other columns. I don't mind if the date is 07/05/2023.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using GNU awk and `gensub()`:

```
$ gawk '{
      print gensub(/(....)-(..)-(..)/,"\\3/\\2/\\1",1)
}' <<< "c_az_6332,2023-12-15,-24.01,BP_Connect,Particulars,details"
```

Output:

```
c_az_6332,15/12/2023,-24.01,BP_Connect,Particulars,details
```

Comment: [The OP only wants to modify the 2nd field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77673370/looking-for-a-awk-gsub-equivalent-to-sed-substitution#comment136939365_77673370) so `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {
      $2=gensub(/(....)-(..)-(..)/,"\\3/\\2/\\1",1,$2); print
}' <<< "c_az_6332,2023-12-15,-24.01,BP_Connect,Particulars,details"`

Comment: @EdMorton Yeah. That's how I started out, had `[0-9]{2}`s all over the place, but then I read the title again: _looking for a awk gsub [|sub|gensub] equivalent to sed substitution_ and decided to show the syntax of `gensub()`.

Answer (score 4):

- Use `,` as field separator for both input (`FS`) and output (`OFS`): `FS = OFS = ","`
- Split the second field (`$2`) at dashes into a named array: `split($2, a, "-")`
- Reformat column 2 using `sprintf` and the array items: `$2 = sprintf("%d/%d/%d", a[3], a[2], a[1])`

```bash
echo "c_az_6332,2023-12-15,-24.01,BP_Connect,Particulars,details" | awk '
  BEGIN { FS = OFS = ","; }
        { split($2, a, "-");
          $2 = sprintf("%d/%d/%d", a[3], a[2], a[1]);
          print;
        }
'
```

```
c_az_6332,15/12/2023,-24.01,BP_Connect,Particulars,details
```

Tested using [GNU Awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/) 5.3.0, [One True Awk](https://github.com/onetrueawk/awk) version 20231124, and [Mawk](http://invisible-island.net/mawk/) version 1.3.4 20231126.

Comment: I just might point out that the semicolon in the BEGIN statement is a typo. I wasn't able to edit this from my side.

Comment: @growler11 You can omit the last semicolon in any block (so this is also true for the one after `print`), but their presence isn't breaking the code either. I like to have them around to facilitate adding further commands. Drop them as you see fit.

Answer (score 2):

Using `gnu awk` you could match the date like pattern in the second field with a regex and 3 capture groups capturing the digits while matching the hyphens.

Then set the value of the second field to the new format using these groups, separated by `/`

```
awk '
BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
match($0, /([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{1,2})-([0-9]{1,2})/, a) {
  $2 = a[3] "/" a[2] "/" a[1]
}1' <<< "c_az_6332,2023-12-15,-24.01,BP_Connect,Particulars,details"
```

Output

```
c_az_6332,15/12/2023,-24.01,BP_Connect,Particulars,details
```

Comment: Very good use of capture group feature

Answer (score 1):

Just to round out your options with date conversion, if you care about adding/removing leading zeros, converting between UTC and locales, adding other derived metrics like week numbers, day of week, etc., you could also consider calling `date` for the transformation, and just reinsert its result. In this simple case, the command performed would be `date +%d/%m/%Y -d 2023-12-15`:

```bash
echo "c_az_6332,2023-12-15,-24.01,BP_Connect,Particulars,details" \
| awk -F, -vOFS=, '{d="date +%d/%m/%Y -d" $2; d|getline $2; close(d); print;}'
```

```
c_az_6332,15/12/2023,-24.01,BP_Connect,Particulars,details
```

Tested using [GNU Awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/) 5.3.0, [One True Awk](https://github.com/onetrueawk/awk) version 20231124, and [Mawk](http://invisible-island.net/mawk/) version 1.3.4 20231126.